# Duvida sobre as informações passadas no SOAP

Tags: soap

Estou pesquisando o funcionamento e utilização do protocolo SOAP, mas me deparei com algumas dúvidas na parte estrutural do protocolo. Há anos eu trabalho programando em linguagem de baixo nível para microcontroladores. Nunca necessitei usar ferramentas de nas camadas mais altas, principalmente na parte de comunicação, então, tenho alguma dificuldade pra entender coisas muito abstratas.

Eu estive analisando algumas requisições usando SOAP e notei que nos elementos do SOAP vão links http, como no elemento "envelope". Abaixo segue um trecho de um código SOAP (o código está incompleto, mas para minha dúvida o restante não é necessário):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:RecepcionarLoteRpsRequest
            xmlns:ns2="http://ws.bhiss.pbh.gov.br">
            <nfseCabecMsg>
                <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
                <cabecalho xmlns="http://www.abrasf.org.br/nfse.xsd"versao="1.00">
                    <versaoDados>1.00</versaoDados>
                </cabecalho>
            </nfseCabecMsg>
            <nfseDadosMsg>
            </nfseDadosMsg>
        </ns2:RecepcionarLoteRpsRequest>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

No envelope vai o seguinte link: "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/".
 Gostaria de saber porque vão esses links. Eles serão acessados em algum momento? Ou é somente a título de informação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esses links, nesse caso são os *name spaces*, de fato lá está **xmlns**, ou seja, ***XML Name Space***. O recurso de *NameSpace* é necessário em XML pois se trata de uma linguagem livre e extensível, na qual você pode criar suas próprias tags, e o *NameSpace* dá um contexto para a tag assinada com um *namespace*, oferecendo assim um meio de evitar possíveis conflitos de nomes entre diferentes tags, veja mais sobre isso [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp).

Além disso, assinando uma tag com um xmlns, você pode atribuir uma estrutura de tags/propriedades esperadas, definido um padrão de XML a ser enviado, o xmlns pode receber qualquer URI válido, porém nesses casos é comum que essa URI aponte para para o seu ***Schema***, veja mais informações sobre *schemas* [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp).

Então, esse link serve para: definir um contexto e estrutura a ser seguida pelo seu XML, e ele pode sim ser acessado pelo recebedor, para validar o seu XML, pois como dito, esse link aponta para o *schema* que seu XML deve seguir, ou seja, sua estrutura esperada.

Espero ter ajudado.

PS: Caso haja a possibilidade, recomendo usar Rest, que é bem mais simples que SOAP.

Comment: Esclareceu bastante a dúvida. Obrigado.